# How to write in firebase on set time?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, alarm

I'm want to build an alarm clock app which will on set time instead of vibrating will write to the firebase database.
I'm using https://github.com/PPartisan/Simple-Alarms code as my base code of alarm clock but I'm facing errors. If sombody has working code of similar application or link that will be helpful.

```
public final class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Firebase fire;
Context thiscontext;
private static final String BUNDLE_EXTRA = "bundle_extra";
private static final String ALARM_KEY = "alarm_key";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(AlarmReceiver.this.thiscontext);


    final Alarm alarm = intent.getBundleExtra(BUNDLE_EXTRA).getParcelable(ALARM_KEY);
    assert alarm != null;
    final int id = AlarmUtils.getNotificationId(alarm);

    final NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final Intent notifIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmLandingPageActivity.class);
    notifIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context, id, notifIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"M_CH_ID");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_white_24dp);
    builder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.accent));
    builder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name));
    builder.setContentText(alarm.getLabel());
    builder.setTicker(alarm.getLabel());
    builder.setVibrate(new long[] {1000,500,1000,500,1000,500});
    builder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
    builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

    fire = new Firebase("https://alarmclock-8u7i2.firebaseio.com/");

    Firebase fireChild = fire.child("Alarm");
    fireChild.setValue("ALARM ON");

    manager.notify(id, builder.build());

    //Reset Alarm manually
    setReminderAlarm(context, alarm);

}
```

The error:`Process: com.banaao.makersplace.progx, PID: 5561
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.banaao.makersplace.progx.service.AlarmReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'context' in setAndroidContext()
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1672)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'context' in setAndroidContext()
        at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setAndroidContext(Firebase.java:972)
        at com.banaao.makersplace.progx.service.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:37)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3187)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1672) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)`

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: @AlexMamo Firebase.setAndroidContext(AlarmReceiver.this.thiscontext); 
This line is giving null point exception error.

Comment: Are you sure that `AlarmReceiver.this.thiscontext` is not `null`? I sure it is.

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm not sure why it is null?